# Form Responses Creating New Google Sheets Tabs Rather then Bucketing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet which is storing the answers to my form and in theory should bucket the responses by the value selected from a drop down for my form labeled "Location of Change". So far the script accurately creates a new sheet from each response and adds a row with that responses information to newly created sheet, but it creates a new sheet for every response rather then add add responses that contain the same value selected from "Location of Change" to the same sheet.

I assume this is happening because there is a disconnect between the `destSheet` variable that looks for the values of the "Location of Change" and the `getSheet()` function, but I could be wrong.

Here is my code:

```
function onSubmit(e) {

  //Open Marketing - Discoveries and Changes - v1
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();


  //Return Spreadsheet that contains this sheet
  var ss = sheet.getParent();

  //Open Marketing - Discoveries and Changes - v1
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(ss.getFormUrl());



  //Destination sheet based on "Location of Change"
  var destSheet = getSheet(ss, e.namedValues["Location of Change"]);

  //Store response in destination sheet
  destSheet.appendRow(e.values);

  function getSheet( spreadsheet, sheetName, headings) {
    spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (sheet == null) {
      sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName);
      if (headings && headings.constructor === Array) {
        sheet.getRange(1,1,1, headings.length).setValues([headings]);
      }
    }
    return sheet;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that [e.namedValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) stores all values as arrays even if there is only one value. So `e.namedValues["Location of Change"]` should be

`e.namedValues["Location of Change"][0]`